# how to implement a main function in polymer apps

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to implement a main function in an app using polymer.

I tried to implement the main function in the dart file, where the polymer code is implemented.
The code is not executed.

Including a second dart script with the main function is not allowed-

Where is my mistake?
Tnx Mica.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? Your app already has a main(), and that is the entry point for the app. Why do you need another main()?

Comment: When you ask 'Where is my mistake?' you should have provided your code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**index.html**

```dart
 <head>
   <!-- <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html"> not necessary anymore (only in elements)-->
   <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
        not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
   <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script> 
        not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.15.0 -->

   <!-- old -->
   <script type="application/dart">
      export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script> 

   <!-- new  -->
   <script type="application/dart">export 'index.dart';</script>
 </head>
 <body>
   ...
   <!-- ... when you use a custom main method (see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17546#c16) -->
   <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
 </body>
```

**index.dart**

**Polymer 0.17.0** (Polymer.js 1.0)

```dart
main() async {
  await initPolymer();
  // Any other code here.
}
```

**Before Polymer 0.17.0**

Polymer **0.16.1** introduces a simpler way of initialization.
Instead of `main()` use a method annotated with `@whenPolymerReady`

```dart
// >= Polymer 0.16.1
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
export 'package:polymer/init.dart';

@whenPolymerReady
void onReady() {
  /// Custom setup code here.
}
```

**Before Polymer.dart 0.16.1**

```dart
// >= Polymer 0.16.0
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

main() {
  initPolymer().then((zone) => zone.run(() {
    // code here works most of the time
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {     
      // some things must wait until onReady callback is called
      // for an example look at the discussion linked below
    });
  }));
}
```

For more details look at the changelog of Polymer 0.16.0 at
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer

**Before Polymer 0.16.0**

```dart
// < Polymer 0.16.0    
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
    // code here works most of the time
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {     
      // some things must wait until onReady callback is called
      // for an example look at the discussion linked below
    });
  });
}
```

[simple tooltip working in dartium, not as javascript](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/7cRLZerHmOo/v9eCBSP0-lYJ)