# dart-polymer update polymer dom elements

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am using this Templates to create a list of notice entries which works fine the first time.

```dart
NoticeList nle = querySelector('#noticeList');
nle.notices = notices;
```

But the second time I call this code gets executed the site doesn't change at all.
Am i missing something?

Thank you

```html
<polymer-element name="notice-list">
   <template>
     <ul id = "noticeEntrys">
        <template repeat="{{notice in notices}}">
          <li>
            <notice-element notice={{notice}}></notice-element>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </template> 
  <script type="application/dart" src="notice_list.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>

 <polymer-element name="notice-element">
  <template>
    <div class="notice">
      <textarea rows="8" readonly>{{notice.getText()}}</textarea>
      <div class="controlls">
        <button type="button" name="delete" on-click={{delete}}>Delete</button>
        <button type="button" name="change" on-click={{change}}>Change</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template> 
  <script type="application/dart" src="notice_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
@CustomTag('notice-list')
class NoticeList extends PolymerElement {
  NoticeList.created() : super.created() {
  }

  @published List<Notice> notices;
}

@CustomTag('notice-element')
class NoticeElement extends PolymerElement {
  NoticeElement.created() : super.created() {
  }

  @published Notice notice;

  void delete(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    Datamanager.removeNotice(notice);
    Controller.updateListe();
  }

  void change(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    Controller.updateActiveElement(notice);
  }

  void setNotice(Notice n)  {
    notice = n;
  }  
}
```

Edit: I update the code the same as i set the list in the first time
      I get the new data via a webservice and the new data is correct

```
static void noticesLoadedPolymerList(List<Notice> notices) {
    NoticeList nle = querySelector('#noticeList');
    nle.setNotices(notices);
  }
```

Edit2: I added a simple integer to display the listsize
       @observable int listSize;
       The value changes if i assign the new list but the displayed content doesn't.

Comment: Can you please add the code how you create update the `notices` list? The code you provided looks fine.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i added some additional information maybe it helps as I am really confused at the moment why it isn't working

Comment: did you try `toObservable(notices)` before assigning it to the polymer element? Still can't see where you create the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489/how-to-implement-a-main-function-in-polymer-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally hat time to solve the problem.

My problem was that i would start polymer like this

```
initPolymer();
```

when i should have started it like this

```
 initPolymer().run(() {
   //initialization and other stuff
 }
```

More about this you can find here https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15379

Answer (score 0):

If you set `notices` in `NoticeList` to a new `List` instance it should recognize the change.
If you assign `notices` in your first attempt and only modify in you second attempt you have to make your `notices` list observable `var notices = toObservable([new Notice('notice1'), new Notice('notice2'), ...])`.

You haven't provided code of your `Notice` class.
It may be necessary to make your `Notice` class observable like:

class Notice extends Object with Observable {
     @observable String text;
   }

This way Polymer recognizes if only a property of a notice instance changes (without changing (add/remove) the `notices` list.