# How do I turn these results into a list for use w/ Polymer's repeat attribute?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In the following code `f.onChildAdded` is an `Instance of '_BroadcastStream<Event>'`:

```
f.onChildAdded.forEach((e) {
  print(e.snapshot.val());
  //TODO: Turn this somehow into a list
 });
```

The `print` outputs each item fine, and now I'd like to turn it into a list that's friendly with Polymer's `repeat="{{item in items }}"` magic.

- How do I turn it into a list? `List myList = new List();` and `myList.add(e.snapshot.val());` isn't helping me there.
- How do I pass that from my `main()` in my index.dart to my-element.dart?

FWIW, here's my project: https://github.com/DaveNotik/dartstack. Any other guidance as I get a handle on this would be great!

Comment: You should move your entire code in `main` but at least the code that accesses some Polymer element into the method body of ` Polymer.onReady.then((_) {`. It's not enough to have this `Polymer.onReady` in your code, it's important that your code is executed **by** this code.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should ensure that your main look like shown here
[how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489)

in your main:

```dart
List myList = new List();

f.onChildAdded.forEach((e) {
  myList.add(e.snapshot.val());
});

(querySelector('your-element') as YourElement).myList = myList;
```

or when you don't want to create a new list each time:

The list field in you custom element should look like

```dart
@observable List myList = toObservable([]);
```

in your main:

```dart
List myList = (querySelector('your-element') as YourElement).myList;

f.onChildAdded.forEach((e) {
  myList.add(e.snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: `malformed type: line 29 pos 53: type 'InboxList' is not loaded
  List inboxItems = (querySelector('inbox-list') as InboxList).inboxItems;` I updated my question with a link to my code (prior to this edit).

Comment: See my comment to your question, I guess this is the cause of this error. Your repo seems not to be up-to-date. I found no line with `querySelector('inbox-list')...`

Comment: I hadn't pushed the broken stuff. Just did. Still errors, including the one above.

Comment: To make this work ` as InboxList` you need to import the dart file of your Polymer element into `index.dart` (in addition to the import in your `index.html`). `import 'packages:dartstack/components/inbox-list/ inbox-list.dart`. Hint: you should not use a dash `-` in file names in Dart. Use the underscore instead.

Comment: Added: `import 'package:../../lib/components/inbox_list/inbox_list.dart';`.

Got: `Uncaught Error: type 'InboxList' is not a subtype of type 'InboxList' in type cast.`

Pushed updates.

Comment: Found elsewhere: "This kind of error are commonly the result of not having a single canonical way to import some library. For example, if a library is imported from the main entry point by going through a 'package:' url and separately going only through relative urls. In such cases Dart treats them as different libraries that happen to use the same name for some types." Looking into how I'm importing.