# Adding Polymer Element results in crash

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I like to use my custom Polymer Element named content-page in my main-html.
Therefore I created a `div` with the `id="contentcontainer"` which contains my `content-page`.
For some reason it crashes, just after clicking on Run and the Dart Editor says: .
When I delete the line `<link rel="import" href="content-page.html">` in main.html, the program isnt crashing, but there seems to be a Problem with the content of my main().

I unfortunately have no specific question, because I dont know where the error might be or where to start. Does someone see some suspicious parts in my code?
Thanks for helping!

main.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var newElement = new Element.tag('content-page');

  querySelector('#contentcontainer').children.add(newElement);
}
```

main.html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="content-page.html">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="contentcontainer">
    <content-page id="contentpage"></content-page>
  </div>
  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

content-page.dart:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('content-page')
class ContentPage extends PolymerElement {

  ContentPage.created() : super.created();
}
```

content-page.html:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="content-page" >

  <template>
    <div>
      ContentPage-Content
    </div>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src="content-page.dart"></script>

</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Please don't use the title of your post for tagging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it's ok. Have you added the transformers to your pubspec.yaml?

```
name: sample
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: any
transformers:
- polymer
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now! I did not add transformers: - polymer. While using this website as reference: https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/ I read over this part accidentally.

Comment: There still was an issue with the other code in my main(), which seems to bot get executed. So I also had to use @Günter Zöchbauer's answer

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this question/answer: [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489) how to use a custom main method in a Polymer project.
This line should contain your file containing your `main` method (see also the answer in the linked question):

```dart
<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
```

this line is then redundant

```dart
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
```

the transformer configuration also needs a list of entry pages if you don't use the latest Polymer version

transformers:

```dart
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
```

Comment: When I use <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script> the content-page isnt visible.

Comment: Because your main method is incomplete, see linked question/answer.

Comment: AND when
I use 
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/polymer/core_drawer_panel/index.html
dart editor says <debug target crashed>

Comment: If it worked without the `entry_points` setting in `pubspec.yaml` then you have probably a version where this isn't necessary anymore but the crash shows that there is still something wrong with your code because my Polymer apps don't crash and I have the `entry_points` still listed without problems.

Comment: I am now using your suggested improvements including the lines of code from your linked answer.
But not the "entry_points"-suggestion.

Comment: It is working, thanks for help! Your pubspec.yaml looks correct, but for my project only @JoaoBiriba's pubspec is working.

Comment: I misinterpreted the CHANGELOG.md. The entry_points don't need to be listed in `build.dart` but still in `pubspec.yaml`.