# Can't create a Polymer Core Element in dart

Tags: dart, polymer

I basically want to create a `<core-tooltip>` tag, not in HTML, but in dart.

So i tried:

```
CoreTooltip tooltip = new CoreTooltip();
CoreTooltip tooltip = document.createElement("core-tooltip"):
CoreTooltip tooltip = new Element.tag("core-tooltip"):
```

got always the same Exception

> Uncaught Error: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'CoreTooltip'

Why does that just not work?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use this method

```dart
document.createElement("core-tooltip"):
```

the other two are fine though.

I assume the element creation fails because the code is in a custom main and is executed before Polymer is done with initialization.

See [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489) for more details.

If you execute the code inside a Polymer elements (for example `attached()` method after `super.attached()`) or in an event handler like `on-click` this will work.

Another possibility is, that you app is missing an HTML import that imports `<core-tooltip>`. Without an import this can't work either.

I tried it with this code and it worked for me

#### app_element.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_tooltip.dart';

@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  AppElement.created() : super.created() {  }

  @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) bool isValidationError;

  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    CoreTooltip tt =  new CoreTooltip();
    print(tt);
  }
}
```

#### app_element.html

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_tooltip.html">

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Actually its inside a function which is called by a button. That should not be the problem, since I can also create Elements like InputElements. And i also imported the core_tooltip.dart.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it myself and report back.

Comment: I guess stopping `pub serve` from within DartEditor had had the same effect then.