# Instantiating polymer element via dart code

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to instantiate a `Polymer` element in my Dart code.

Here's my element:

```dart
@CustomTag('card-component')
class CardComponent extends PolymerElement {
  @published
  String playerName;

  CardComponent.created() : super.created();
}
```

So far the only way I found to be working was:

```dart
Element y = new Element.tag('card-component');
```

But what I would really like to do, would be to access the values of my component by their accessors (instead of by attributes of `HtmlElement`). Is there a way to instantiate a `CardComponent` directly in Dart without using the `Element.tag` way? I tried using the `CardComponent.created()` method in multiple ways but it didn't work either.

In case you wonder why I want to do this, well I would like to pass parameters to my constructor, or even use a factory to create the component in an ideal world.

Edit: After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26399434/505810) I ended up being able to do what I wanted. I just had to had this to my component

```dart
factory CardComponent(String playerName) => document.createElement("card-component")
  ..attributes = {
    "playerName" : playerName
};
```

And then instantiate it like this:

```dart
CardComponent myNewCard = new CardComponent("Pacane");
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997989

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean by "to access the values of my component by their accessors (instead of by attributes of `HtmlElement`)"

```dart
(new Element.tag('card-component') as CardComponent)
    ..playerName = 'blabla';
```

adding a custom factory constructor allows you to use the element as if it had a normal constructor

```dart
@CustomTag('card-component')
class CardComponent extends PolymerElement {
  @published
  String playerName;

  CardComponent.created() : super.created();

  factory CardComponent CardComponent() {
    return new Element.tag('card-component');
  }
}
```

```dart
var cc = new CardComponent()..playerName = 'blabla';
```

If you want to do this from `main()` not from within another component, ensure that `main()` contains the Polymer (initialization code [why am I getting type error on polymer.dart element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876713), [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489))

Comment: Thanks for the `as CardComponent` trick! But the factory is really want I wanted. :)