# How do I add a valid default constructor to a dart polymer class?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The following code defines the Polymer element
What do I need as a valid default constructor for this class?
My question is what is needed for a proper constructor

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'lib/NPIDefs.dart';
import 'dart:html';


/**
 * A Polymer click counter element.
 */
@CustomTag('detail-panel')
class NPIDetailPanel extends PolymerElement {
  @published @observable NPIRecord record;
  @observable String detailPanelICON = "unfold-less";

  NPIDetailPanel.created() : super.created() {
  }

  setValue(NPIRecord npiRec) {
    record = npiRec;
  }

  void dremoveDetailPanel() {
    Element e;
    e = shadowRoot.querySelector('#dpanel');

    if(e != null) {
      e.remove();
    }  
  }
```

The code below gets a The class 'NPIDetailPanel' does not have a default constructor error 
Please show how to do a default constructor
in the definition of the class

```dart
void addDetailPanel(Event e) {
  NPIDetailPanel e1;
  e1 = new NPIDetailPanel();
}

/* How do I add a proper default constructor? */
```

Comment: Hint: always add the `dart` tag to Dart related questions to get fast response. Much more people monitor this tag than other sub-tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of a Polymer element using `new Element.tag('some-tag');`
Just add a factory constructor that contains this to your Polymer element class.

```dart
@CustomTag('detail-panel')
class NPIDetailPanel extends PolymerElement {

  factory NPIDetailPanel NPIDetailPanel() => new Element.tag('detail-panel'); // <== added

  @published @observable NPIRecord record;
  @observable String detailPanelICON = "unfold-less";

  NPIDetailPanel.created() : super.created() {
  }

  setValue(NPIRecord npiRec) {
    record = npiRec;
  }

  void dremoveDetailPanel() {
    Element e;
    e = shadowRoot.querySelector('#dpanel');

    if(e != null) {
      e.remove();
    }  
  }
}
```

see also [Instantiating polymer element via dart code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345396)