# Paper Elements only creates HtmlElements in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, web-component

I have a simple component that contains a list of employees defined as following:

```
@Component(selector: 'employee-list', templateUrl:
    'employee_list.html', cssUrl: 'employee_list.css')
class EmployeeListComponent extends ShadowRootAware {
...
}
```

I would like to use a `PaperFab` element in my code, as an action button and would like to alter it on the fly (e.g. change the icon).

There is a link to the element definition in the HTML:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_fab.html">
```

Creating the element programmatically:

```
var fab = new PaperFab(); 
print(fab is PaperFab) // false
```

or

```
var fab = new Element.tag('paper-fab') as PaperFab;
// Casts error: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 
//    'PaperFab' in type cast.
```

The same happens when selecting the element through the

```
var fab = _shadowRoot.querySelection("#fabButton");
print(fab is PaperFab) // false
```

Is it possible to access paper elements from a custom element? Or should you use the `innerHTML` instead, which could work but breaks the component idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Polymer initialization is missing. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982658/217408 for more details.

You need to ensure Polymer is initialized properly before you can create elements by running your code from within `zone.run(() {... }` or `initPolymer().run(() { ... }` or one of the Polymer life-cycle callbacks.
If you initialize Angular in `run` you can create Polymer elements everywhere in Angular code as well.

This is the default way to create instances or Polymer elements imperatively

```dart
var fab = new Element.tag('paper-fab') as PaperFab;
```

but the core- and paper-elements have got a factory constructor which allows them to be instantiated using new as well

```dart
new PaperFab();
```

If you build your own Polymer element you need to add a factory constructor yourself to be able to create new instances using `new`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616062/217408 for more details.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed part of the solution. Requires a few addition in combination with AngularDart.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Günter's answer:

In the `main.dart` the construction is now as follows to combine it with AngularDart:

```dart
void main() {
  initPolymer().then((zone) => zone.run(() {
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
      Logger.root
        ..level = Level.FINEST
        ..onRecord.listen((LogRecord r) {
          print(r.message);
        });

      applicationFactory().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();
    });
  }));
}
```

And to resolve any problems with the smoke library add the polymer transformer to the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yml
transformers:
- angular:
    html_files:
    ...
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```