# Dart polymer 'does not have default constructor'

Tags: templates, constructor, dart, dart-polymer

I have several templates (Polymer and Dart) working fine.  But I cannot understand the Dart editor complaining in the case where I have a (my) template within another of (my) templates.
I have a template for "staff" - it extends PolymerElement.
I have a template for "person" - it extends PolymerElement.
I cannot dynamically create a "person" in "staff", with the complaint:  person 'does not have default constructor'.
Here is my code for staff:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 't_person.dart';
@CustomTag('t-staff')
class tstaff extends PolymerElement {
   tstaff.created() : super.created() {}
void addPersonButton(){
   tPerson tpe = new tPerson(); //ERROR HERE 'tPerson does not have default constructor'
    ....
```

Here is my code for tPerson (no errors):

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('t-person')
class tPerson extends PolymerElement {
  tPerson.created() : super.created() {   }
 }
```

Am I not allowed to use templates in this way? Is there a limit on the depth of children templates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating polymer element via dart code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345396/instantiating-polymer-element-via-dart-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new instance of a Polymer element you need to do it like `new Element.tag('t-person');`.
If you add this to the default constructor you get a more convenient way.

```dart
@CustomTag('t-person')
class tPerson extends PolymerElement {

  tPerson.created() : super.created();

  factory tPerson tPerson() {
    return new Element.tag('t-person');
  }
}
```