# Passing an object reference to Dart script of Polymer Element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to pass an object reference to the Dart script associated with a Polymer element.  I have found the element in the DOM but I can't figure out how to call a method in the Dart associated with the element or any other way to dynamically pass an object to the Polymer element to be displayed.

Comment: Very helpful and so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just get a reference by using for example `querySelector('#someid')` and just assign the value to a field or setter or call a method and pass it as an argument.

```dart
querySelector('#someid').someField = someValue;
querySelector('#someid').setValue(someValue);
```

This might produce a hint in DartEditor but should still work when the code is executed. To get rid of the hint you can "cast" like

```dart
(querySelector('#someid') as MyComponent).someField = someValue;
querySelector('#someid') as MyComponent).setValue(someValue);
```

You need to import `MyComponent` to make this work.

If this doesn't something with your code might be wrong. For example the `main()` method if you have one. See [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489) for more details.

If nothing of the above works, please add code to your question that shows what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: That worked well but I did need to use shadowRoot.querySelector, I am not sure why.

Comment: I didn't add it because you wrote that selecting the element is already working. Without `shadowRoot.` `querySelector` searches the children of the element (the content) not the elements in the elements template (shadow DOM).