# webcomponents.js fails with error 404

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I'm seeing exceptions in my console when running my dart app related to webcomponents.js
Everything is running as expected, should I ignore this exception?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/packages/web_components/webcomponents.js
```

[image]

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: alm
description: alm
dependencies:
  browser: any
  # bootjack: any
  polymer: ">0.15.3"
  paper_elements: any
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.html
```

index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <!--
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="packages/bootjack/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  -->
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">  
</head>
<body unresolved>
  <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>

  <div id="more-buttons">
    <paper-button raised class="colored">colored</paper-button>
    <paper-button raised disabled>disabled</paper-button>
  </div>

  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
//import 'package:bootjack/bootjack.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_button.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';

void main() {

  print("begin");

  initPolymer().run(() {
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {

      DivElement div = querySelector("#more-buttons");

      div.appendHtml("123");

      PaperButton y = new PaperButton();
      y.text = "KOTS";
      y.raised = true;
      div.append(y);

      PaperInput x = new PaperInput();
      x.value = "KOTS";
      div.append(x);

    });
  });

  print("end");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you run into this issue:https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21810
It's fixed now but a workaround is included in the dicussion.

Comment: This is a brand new project, will try deleting .pub anyways and see if that solves it.

Comment: After deleting .pub and doing a pub get, "Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 512 byte" - So pub is running out of memory. Will investigate further.

Comment: Pub is probably running into an infinite loop. Try to delete your pub cache folder. On Mac and Linux, this directory defaults to ~/.pub-cache. On Windows, it goes in AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache.

Comment: Ah, now it's running perfectly, thanks Timo D and Fox32!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fox32 suggested that I delete my ~/.pub folder and do a pub get again.
After doing that, I ran into pub running out of memory the whole time.

Timo D suggested I also delete ~/.pub-cache which I did.
After another pub get and pub serve, it's running perfectly.

Thanks Timo D and Fox32 !!