# removing polymer elements in dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

i am adding polymer elements. i want to remove the element(self) on click on its(own) image. as per encapsulation i will have to make the parent delete the child. but this requires requires generating polymer elements for the parent too( am i right here??). children.add not defined for polymer elements.how do i do this, i plan to do some checks before adding the polymer element to the form .

Already read:
[How to remove a child component with a delete button in the child itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406328/how-to-remove-a-child-component-with-a-delete-button-in-the-child-itself)

[How do I fire a custom event from Polymer Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971511/how-do-i-fire-a-custom-event-from-polymer-dart)

[How do you dispatch and listen for custom events in Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040193/how-do-you-dispatch-and-listen-for-custom-events-in-polymer?lq=1)

what do i pass through dispatch event??

init-item.html

```
<polymer-element name="init-item" >
  <template>
    <input type="image" src="button_minus_red.gif" on-click="{{remove}}" width = "15" height ="15">
    {{Name}}<br> 
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="init-item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

init-item.dart

```
@HtmlImport('init-item.html')
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('init-item')
class PItem extends PolymerElement{
  @observable String Name='hello';
  void remove(){
    Name='';

  }
```

so presently on clicking the image the name attribute gets reset. but this happens only on a subsequent  click event generated from main.dart. This is due to data binding. how do i initiate two way data binding.??

main.html (polymer tags **not** added inspite of suggestion. couldnt figure it out)

```
...
<form  id="youritems">
</form>
...
```

Polymer items added to above tag.

main.dart

```
...
main() async{
.. initPolymer().then((_) {});
}
..
...{..
var input = new InputElement(type:"image");
input.onClick.listen((p){
            p.preventDefault();
            populateYourPlayers(teams[i]);
          });
}
void populateItems(String name){
  Polymer.onReady.then((_) { 
    var pl = new Element.tag('player-item');
    pl.playerName = name;
    yourPlayer.children.add(pl);
    });
}
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename the click handler from `remove` to for example `removeItem` then you can just call `remove()` within the handler and it will work.

```dart
<input type="image" src="button_minus_red.gif" on-click="{{removeItem}}" width = "15" height ="15">
```

```dart
void removeItem(){
  Name='';
  remove(); // removes the init-item (self)
}
```

`remove` is an existing method on all elements. If you name your own method `remove` you override the default `remove` method and the original can't be called anymore (except from within your element with `super.remove();`)

Comment: how do i code an event in one polymer to change attributes of another polymer, them not having parent child relation??

Comment: `import 'dart:html' as dom; import 'other_element.dart'; ... (dom.querySelector('* /deep/ other-element') as OtherElement).someField =  false;` This searches the whole document for `<other-element>` even when it is inside the shadow DOM of another element.

Comment: aim was to have an event in polymer a to change on attribute in polymer b. (within a.dart: imported b into a. did a query selector for element b. called the function which moded the value. the value changes(print)). but not updated on ui . modded variable is observable.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you want to know. Please create a new question with some code that shows what you try to accomplish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593782/event-in-one-polymer-to-change-attributes-of-another-polymer-them-not-having-pa