# event in one polymer to change attributes of another polymer, them not having parent child relation

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

An event handler in Polymer element `a` should change an attribute in Polymer element `b`.

I tried (within `a.dart`):
- imported `b.dart`
- query selector for element `b`.
- called the function which modifies the value.
- the value changes(print)). but not updated on UI.
- modified variable is observable

a.html

```dart
<template>
    <input type="image" src="button_minus_red.gif" on-click="{{removePlayer}}" width = "15" height ="15">
    {{playerName}}:{{playerCost}}<br>
  </template>
```

b.html

```dart
<template>
    <h1>Team Size:{{playerCount}}</h1>
    <h1>Team Value</h1>
    <br>
  </template>
```

b.dart

```dart
@CustomTag('team-item')
class TeamItem extends PolymerElement{
  @observable int playerCount =0;
  void reduceCount(){
    playerCount -= 1;
    print("PLayerCount");
    print(playerCount);
  }
  TeamItem.created(): super.created();
}
```

a.dart

```dart
@CustomTag('player-item')
class PlayerItem extends PolymerElement{
  @observable String playerName;
  @observable String playerCost;
  void removePlayer() {
    print('dispatching from child');
    querySelector("#playerCounts").reduceCount();
    remove();
  }PlayerItem.created(): super.created();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you only search the children of `a`.
If you want to search the whole page you need to

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;
...
(dom.querySelector('* /deep/ #playerCounts') 
    as TeamPlayer).reduceCount();
```

Comment: but the variable playercount not getting updated on ui. inspite of its value being modified

Comment: I can't imagine how this can not be updated when the print statement prints the reduced value.

Comment: could this be possibly because the reduceCount call is not coming from main.dart??

Comment: No, if it would be called from main it would be more likely not work.

Comment: Can you make your project available on GitHub? I could take a look tomorrow.

Comment: At first, there should be **no** application source/resource files in the project directory - see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html. The client files should be moved to `web` or `lib`. Polymer needs an entry for the entry page in the transfomrer configuration - see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html.

Comment: I created a pull request in your Git repo with some fixes but I didn't yet find where the code is your question is about because I have to leave. I'll have another look later

Comment: Dart file names shouldn't contain a `-`. Use `_` instead.