# Cannot use initPolymer().run in DART 1.9.3, Polymer 0.16.1+2

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I am trying to upgrade to DART 1.9.3, Polymer 0.16.1

Code that worked before:

```
initPolymer().run((){
   ... some code
}
```

now reports that

> "the method run() is not defined for Future`<Zone>`"

Is this a known change/defect?
What would be a workaround?

Please, advise.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489/how-to-implement-a-main-function-in-polymer-apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Polymer.dart [release notes for 0.16.0](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/reference/release-notes/#polymer-0160) have:

> ### Breaking Changes
>
> The initPolymer() method now returns a Future instead of a Zone. This is not completed until all @HtmlImport imports have finished loading. See the [changelog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer#changelog) for more information and a few example migration paths.

Which suggests that you should put your `... some code` inside a function called `realMain()` and call it like:

```
main() => initPolymer().then((zone) => zone.run(realMain));
realMain() => ...
```

Or:

```
main() => initPolymer();

@initMethod
realMain() => ...
```