# How do I programatically select and disable a PaperButton?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to migrate from Bootstrap to Polymer/Paper and I've got a lot of situations where I have to enable/disable buttons that were previously accessed as ButtonElements and then .disabled=true/false.

So for example I've got a paper button I'm trying to access and enable/disable via querySelector as such:

```
PaperButton nextWeekButton = querySelector("#nextweekbutton");
nextWeekButton.disabled=!_status;
```

But I am getting the error: `type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'PaperButton' of 'nextWeekButton'.`

I get the same variety of message if I try as an `InputElement` or `ButtonElement`. If I try to get it as an `HtmlElement` then of course I get the `"setter 'disabled' is not defined..."`

I was going to start playing around with attribute setting but really shouldn't there be a way to do this that's like the `ButtonElement`? Just want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Update: For now I am doing this

```
void disableButton(Element _e, bool _status) {
  if(!_status) {
    _e.setAttribute("disabled","true");
  } else {
    _e.attributes.remove("disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that your code is executed before Polymer is initialized. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982658/217408 how to initialize Polymer when you have a custom main method.

Comment: Thank you! I really badly wanted you to be incorrect with this since I spent too much time trying to figure this out and that was too simple! But that was indeed the issue! I appreciate your direction.