# In Dart, how do I get the width of a table cell?

Tags: html, dart, dart-html

OK, there seem to be lots of questions+answers related to this topic, but I cannot find a precise answer, mainly because the they seem to be related to **setting** a cell width. I'm not interested in that. Apologies if I've missed it!

I want to draw a canvas in a cell, which has not had it's width set.

I have a TableCellElement CELL and I can display innerHTML fine. But I want to add a child canvas to CELL, so I need the cell width.

CELL.style.width, CELL.clientWidth, CELL.client, etc all return zero, always.

Is this possibly a Dart bug, am I going about it incorrectly, or is it not possible? Should I find the column the cell is in (how?), and then find the width of that? 
Cheers
Steve

Answer (score 2):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table,td {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="id1">xxx</td><td id="id2">yyyy</td><td id="id3"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  printWidth('id1');
  printWidth('id2');
  printWidth('id3');
}

printWidth(String id) {
  print('${id}:');
  CssStyleDeclaration elem = querySelector('#${id}').getComputedStyle();

  print('width: ${elem.width}');
  print('borderLeftWidth: ${elem.borderLeftWidth}');
  print('borderRightWidth: ${elem.borderRightWidth}');
  print('paddingLeft: ${elem.paddingLeft}');
  print('paddingRight: ${elem.paddingRight}');
}
```

prints

```
id1:
width: 24px
borderLeftWidth: 1px
borderRightWidth: 1px
paddingLeft: 1px
paddingRight: 1px
id2:
width: 32px
borderLeftWidth: 1px
borderRightWidth: 1px
paddingLeft: 1px
paddingRight: 1px
id3:
width: 0px
borderLeftWidth: 1px
borderRightWidth: 1px
paddingLeft: 1px
paddingRight: 1px
```

Comment: Hi Gunter, Many thanks for that.  My table is fully generated/dynamic - I only  define <table></table> in the html file.  I tried setting the cell.id='#a'+cell.hashcode.toString()  (when I create the cell). Then I use your method above, but the returned "elem" is always null. I call it immediately after setting the cell.id.  :(     Cheers, Steve

Comment: The `#` is part of the selector not of the id. `#` is to tell `querySelector` it should look for the id, not the tag name. See my code, only in Dart code `#` is used but not in the HTML part.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, my typo here. My code was er... 'correct'. But I have now tried cell.id=''A"+hashcode.tostring()  and the query as querySelector('#${id}').  No change.

Comment: I'm not sure what your last comment means. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Hi Gunter. Thanks for persevering with me! No it doesn't work. I still get a null element. I've tried a few variations. I will play further, and set one cell element id to something recognisable, and try to retrieve it. Might be a shadowRoot problem.  I'll report back when I find a solution. cheers, Steve

Comment: So, you are using Polymer? Do you have a custom `main()` method where you execute this code or is this code inside a Polymer element? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20982658/217408

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using Polymer, and my table is inside a polymer template. cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
      cell.contentEdge.width;
```