# Add event listener in Dart for events in polymer

Tags: dart, polymer, core-elements, core-scroll-header-panel

Need add event listener for **core-header-transform**, from **core-scroll-header-panel** element in dart package **core_elements**. How i can do that?

**app.html:**

```
<template>
  <core-scroll-header-panel id="scroll-panel" condenses flex>
    <core-toolbar class="tall">
        <header id="main-header" horizontal layout flex>
            <div id="application-name">
                status
                <server-status></server-status>
            </div>
        </header>
      <div class="bottom indent title">title</div>
    </core-toolbar> </template>
```

Dart **app.dart:**

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('some-app')
class SomeApp extends PolymerElement {
  Some.created() : super.created();

  onReady(){
    var coreScrollHeader = $['scroll-panel'];

    coreScrollHeader.on['core-header-transform'].listen((event){
      print('core-header-transform');
    });
  }
}
```

in **pubspec.yaml**: polymer: "^0.16.3+3"

Comment: Your code seems to do that, so what is the actual problem? You want to know how to do it from outside Polymer? It's basically the same as in your code but you need to initialize Polymer "manually" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489/how-to-implement-a-main-function-in-polymer-apps/20982658#20982658

Comment: But, i must see 'core-header-transform' in browser console when i scroll page.
I try @whenPolymerReady, and my index.html now see like that: https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/e947f15d44659bcd1db0

Comment: `$[xxx]` doesn't work outside a Polymer element. You have to use `querySelector()` instead.

Comment: With querySelector() https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/e947f15d44659bcd1db0 it's not worked to.

Comment: Try `var coreScrollHeader = querySelector('* /deep/ #scroll-panel');` instead. When you execute it from outside an element you need to tell it to search into elements shadow DOM.

Comment: Thanks! That's what i need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first ensure Polymer is properly initialized (for details see [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489/how-to-implement-a-main-function-in-polymer-apps/20982658#20982658))

The register the event listener like:

```
  @whenPolymerReady
  onReady(){
    var coreScrollHeader = querySelector('* /deep/ #scroll-panel');

    coreScrollHeader.on['core-header-transform'].listen((event){
      print('core-header-transform');
    });
  }
```