# Dart Cordova+Polymer+Angular2+FastClick

Tags: cordova, dart, dart-polymer, angular, fastclick.js

How can I eliminate the ~300ms tap delay on iOS devices when using Dart Polymer's paper-elements together with Angular 2?

e.g. In an Angular 2 component, if I have an HTML template that includes `paper-button` with `(click)="myFunc()"`, in iOS devices, myFunc is called after this dreaded infamous delay.

I've tried using FastClick.js, but after I attach it (to the body, or a specific paper-button), the element is no longer clickable, I can still see the ripple effect when I tap it, but the method is not getting called (on mobile, however in desktop browsers it works as usual), it also has the same effect on `paper-input`(s), it's not getting focused.

Can something be done about it?
Maybe a Dart/Angular2 equivalent of FastClick.js could be made?

### Update 1

It's worth mentioning that under a UIWebView (cordova), I couldn't get Angular2.dart and Polymer.dart to work at the same time, it seems they don't play well together, which is also a blocker, could use some help on that as well.

### Update 2

Sources:
https://github.com/aabluedragon/dart_issue_polymer_angular2_cordova

### Update 3

- **White screen issue:** It appears that the white screen problem on first run under Cordova is related to Polymer; it has nothing to do with Angular2.
- **Tap delay:** Using Polymer's `on-tap` event prevents the tap delay, however, that means you cannot use Angular2's (click) events, which don't handle taps nicely as Polymer.

Comment: Did you enable CSP for Polymer + Dart2js

Comment: I've enabled a global CSP: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`.
And in Cordova's config.xml: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />`.

Funny thing is, it works in Safari and not under Cordova, and that's just one part of the problem, also have the tap delay thing.

Comment: I think you need to enable it twice in pubspec.yaml. I have no knowledge about the tap delay.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, it partially solved the white Cordova UIWebView issue, by partially I mean that at the first time compilation is commencing, the UIWebView remains blank even after it completes compiling, however if I relaunch the Cordova app it's showing the element (because it's already compiled), so it's not yet completely solved.

Comment: `$dart2js` alsi allows to enable CSP. There are some related questions on SO about this. I'm only on my phone  and therefore  leave it to you to look it up ;-)

Comment: You still haven't enabled CSP for `$dart2js` in your code in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks Gunter, but I've tried adding `- $dart2js: csp: true` just below the polymer transformer, compilation as usual worked fine, but it didn't help with the white screen issue. I'll commit it to my github issue repo to show it.

Comment: Doesn't look like you are initializing Polymer properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489/how-to-implement-a-main-function-in-polymer-apps/20982658#20982658

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get FastClick to work with Angular 2+ (Angular 4 in my case), but I found a different solution called [ng2-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-events) which has multiple features, one of them being *support for touch events in angular 4*.

```
# for angular 5
npm install --save ng2-events
# for angular 4
npm install --save ng2-events@3.1.0
```

Then in app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {TouchEventModule} from "ng2-events/lib/touch";

@NgModule({
    imports: [TouchEventModule],
    exports: [TouchEventModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your template:

```
<button (down)="touchAction()">Try this on mobile device</button>
```

Comment: It works, but it seems to cause event bubbling. In Android, clicks are fired twice. Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: @francojay It's been a while since I used this.  But I think you can pass the event object like `<button (down)="touchAction($event)">Try this on mobile device</button>` and then in your `touchAction()` function you receive the event and call event.stopPropagation() like: `public touchAction(event: any): void { event.stopPropagation(); }`.  Sorry I don't have more info. Good luck!