# Polymer.dart not loading when compiled to JavaScript

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am experiencing some very odd problems with Polymer.dart when compiled to javascript. It works fine in Dartium. This app did work a couple of months ago. However Polymer has undergone lots of changes since then, so I have had to make loads of changes just to get it to compile. I have tried this in polymer 3.2 through to the latest build in pub, all behave the same. I am running an up to date Dart install on the stable branch.

I get the following Javascript error:

> TypeError: $document.register is not a function

On the last line of the js below. The tag variable is "polymer-element".

```dart
})(H.convertDartClosureToJS(W._callAttributeChanged$closure(), 4)))};
proto = Object.create(baseConstructor.prototype, properties);
t2 = H.makeLeafDispatchRecord(interceptor);
Object.defineProperty(proto, init.dispatchPropertyName, {value: t2, enumerable: false,    writable: true, configurable: true});
options = {prototype: proto};
if (!t1)
options.extends = extendsTagName;
$document.register(tag, options);
```

From what I can see the polyfills aren't loading so the document.register method hasn't been declared.

Below is from my HTML File

```html
<head>
    <script src="index.dart" type="application/dart"></script>

    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
</head>
```

My index.dart looks like

```dart
void main() {
    window.alert("Dart Lives!");

    initPolymer().run(() => initPresentation());
}


void initPresentation() {
    //Show the first screen
}
```

When running under Javascript I get the alert box showing followed by the Javascript error. So I don't think there is anything wrong with the basic dart environment.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This has changed.
An up-to-date answer is here
[Polymer querySelector working on DartVM but not in Chrome after compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932180/)

**OLD**

Hard to tell.

I think `index.dart` should look like

```html
<head>  
  <script type='application/dart'>
    export 'index.dart';
  </script>
</head>
```

or

```html
<body>

  ...
  <script type='application/dart' src='index.dart'></script>
</body>
```

see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17546#c16